# Binary file containing all ASCII characters

Tags: c++, vim, binary, ascii

Is there a binary file (.dat file) that contains all 256 ASCII characters? I'd like to test it on my Huffman compression algorithm.

When creating a file normally using a text editor like vim, I won't be able to add in the weird characters like control characters, etc. I wonder if anyone knows whether there is such a file ready to use or if I can make one myself.

Comment: Just to be precise: there are only 128 characters in ASCII.

Comment: Moreover, with `vim` you can type all control characters within the 128 ASCII, by preceding them by CTRL-V.

Comment: I guess I'm referring to the extended ASCII codes then.

Comment: @maregor you're just referring to bytes, no particular encoding.

Comment: Also, find a hex editor and learn to use it. That's the equivalent of a text editor, but for non-text files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create one with `for(i=0;i<256;i++)printf("%c",i);`.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds pretty straightforward.
What is the problem?

```
void MakeFile(void)
{
    unsigned char ascii[128] = {0};
    for(int i=1; i<ARRAY_SIZE(ascii); ++i)
    {
        ascii[i] = ascii[i-1]+1;
    }

    FILE* fp = fopen("all_ascii.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) 
    {
        return;
    }
    fwrite(ascii, ARRAY_SIZE(ascii), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of such a file, but you could use the integer representation, or the hex, etc of those characters. You could check to see if they can be represented by using the function [isprint()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isprint/), which will return false if it can't be printed.

So what I would do is use a loop and start at the first character, then use that function to determine whether it can be represented in a character form, or whether you will need to express it some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Random.org](https://www.random.org/).
There is a [white noise generator](https://www.random.org/audio-noise/), it generates a audiofile, but you may use it for your compression tests.